# Javascript para o Angular

Tags: angularjs

Pessoal sou meio novo no Angular, alguém poderia me ajudar a converter esse código em javascript para angular.

```js
 window.onload = function(){
  var campo1 = document.getElementById("campo1").value;

  if(campo1 == 0.00){
   document.getElementById("icon").style.display = "none";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("icon").style.display = "block";

  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="checkbox" />
<input type="text" id="campo1" value="0.00" />
<div id="icon">
 <img src="lupa.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Pesquisa sobre controllers. E na página inicial do Angular você já conseguiria resolver essa dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

- Vincule o valor de `campo1` a uma variável no escopo atual;
- use este valor como comparação para via `ng-if` ou `ng-show`.

Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
function SampleController($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.valor = 0.00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="valor" />
      <div id="icon" ng-if="valor!=0" >
        <img src="http://orig05.deviantart.net/c360/f/2012/049/c/3/lupa_png_by_hannaabigail1-d4q6jmc.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Ajudou muito.
Só fiquei com uma duvida, como faço para pegar um valor fixo do value.

Comment: @DiBoa Sempre um prazer ajudar! Eu não entendi direito, poderia elaborar usa pergunta mais um pouco?

Comment: Então amigo, em meu input já vem um valor no value fixo por exemplo value="10".

Comment: @DiBoa o value sempre será sobrescrito pelo valor do modelo vinculado.

Comment: vlw Deu Certo, também consegui usando o ng-show="".

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, você define os valores iniciais para o seu formulário no controller. Desta forma você terá um valor inicial definido quando a aplicação começar.

Veja esse exemplo que eu escrevi: https://jsbin.com/halerewuba/1/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exemploApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ExemploCtrl as ctrl">
      <form>
        <p>
          <label>Nome:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.nome">
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>Idade:</label>
          <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.idade">
        </p>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <div>
        <h3>Debug:</h3>
        <p>
          {{ctrl}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('exemploApp', [])
        .controller('ExemploCtrl', function() {
          var ctrl = this;

          // Valores iniciais para os campos do formulário
          ctrl.nome = "";
          ctrl.idade = 18;

        })
      ;

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```